# I don't understand the point of the call() method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, methods

Please look at the code below and explain: what am I doing wrong?

```
    function doStuff(a, b){
      return a + b + 1 ;
    }

    var myContext = {
       c: 1, 
       d: 3
    };

// myContext = this (result => 5)
    doStuff.call(myContext,myContext.c,myContext.d)

// ... so why doesn't the below work? (result => NaN)
    doStuff.call(myContext,this.c,this.d)

// To make the above work, i must replace "this" with "myContext" (result => 5)...
    doStuff.call(myContext,myContext.c,myContext.d)

// ...which is no different to... 
    doStuff(myContext.c,myContext.d)

// ...so what was the point of call() method?
```

Am I being thick?

Comment: `Function.prototype.call()` sets `this` inside the function, so if you have `function doStuff(){ return this.a + this.b + 1 }` you can do `doStuff.call(myContext);`

Comment: A function's *this* is a parameter that is part of its [*execution context*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3), it isn't "context" itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main point of `call` is to set the value of `this` **within** the function. Since your `doStuff` doesn't use `this` *within* the function, using `call` with it is pointless.

Here's an example where it matters:

```
function doStuff(a, b) {
    return this.sum(a, b);
}
var obj = {
    sum: function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }
};
console.log(doStuff.call(obj, 3, 4)); // 7, because `obj` has a `sum` property
console.log(doStuff(3, 4));           // Fails with an error that `this.sum` is not a function
```

---

> so why doesn't the below work? (result => NaN)
>
> `doStuff.call(myContext,this.c,this.d)`

Because `this.c` is evaluated *before* the call to `doStuff`, using whatever the current `this` value is. How you're probably calling that code, `this` is (in loose mode) the global object (the window object, on browsers), which probably doesn't have a `c` or `d` property. (In strict mode, again making assumptions about how you're calling that, you'd get an exception, because `this` is `undefined` and you can't retrieve properties from `undefined`.)

Comment: It makes sense now. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

---

`.call` and `.apply` are Function methods that 'manipulate' what `this` means inside a function.

`doStuff.call(myContext, myContext.c, myContext.d)`:
here you've set `myContext` as context for `doStuff` function 
and you may refer to it inside by using `this`, 
and you've passed two arguments to it: myContext.c, myContext.d, 
it works as you've intended...

---

`doStuff.call(myContext, this.c, this.d)`:
again `myContext` is context for `doStuff()`
**but** you've passed `.c` and `.d` properties of what `this` points to 
in context in which it appears (global object, window) in your case.
So `doStuff`'s context is **myContext**, and parameters are 2 `undefined`s, 
because `this === window` in context where you are calling the function, 
and you are passing `.c` and `.d` properties of `global` into the function.
you are actually getting this: `return undefined + undefined + 1;` (NaN)

---

if you redefine 'doStuff' like this:

```
function doStuff () {

  return this.a + this.b + 1;

  // here it looks whatever this is set to 
  // by `.call()` or `.apply()` methods

}
```

and call it like this:

```
var sum = doStuff.call(myContext);

// notice that using `.call` here 
// means that 'myContext' is manualy set 
// as `this` value inside the function above
// and is refered to by dynamic variable 'this'
```