# What is wrong in my example of using the 'call' method in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, call

I'm trying to learn OOP on my own using AS3, and I've given myself a challenge for that purpose. Because it's quite a complex one, I'm trying to understand useful tools in AS3.

At any rate, the `function.call` (AS3 API's doc. [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html#call())) method looks quite interesting, and I think I would be able to put that into use, however I apparently don't understand fully what it does and how it works. JavaScript seems to have an equivalent that looks pretty straightforward to use. (I saw [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574587/i-dont-understand-the-point-of-the-call-method-in-javascript) with the same question as mine, but in JS)

Here's an example of what I thought the `function.call` would do.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public var foo:Foo;
        public var bar:Bar;

        public function Main() 
        {
            foo = new Foo();
            bar = new Bar();

            trace(bar.barProperty); //Hello World!

            //I expect the 'foo.BarProp' to be called with this==bar.
            foo.value = foo.BarProp.call(bar); //ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property barProperty not found on Main.as$0.Foo and there is no default value.

            trace(foo.value); //Expected output: Hello World!
        }

    }

}

class Foo {

    public var value:String;

    public function Foo() {}

    public function BarProp():String {
        return this.barProperty;
    }
}

class Bar {

    public var barProperty:String = "Hello World!";

    public function Bar() {}
}
```

All right, so what is it that I'm just not getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `return this.barProperty` should be giving you compile errors, since there is no `barProperty` on `this` where you've written that code.

Second of all, I don't think `Function/call()` can change the meaning of `this` for class instance methods. It works for object functions:

```
var foo:Object = {
    getBarProperty: function(){
        return this.barProperty;
    }
}

var bar:Object = { // or use your Bar class
    barProperty: "Hello World"
}

trace(foo.getBarProperty.call(bar)); // "Hello World"

foo.getBarProperty(); // "undefined", because "foo" does not have a "barProperty"
```

This is the same as Javascript, but Javascript does not have classes and instance functions, and [`this` is infamously not always lexical](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), so using `call()` and `apply()` with a `thisArg` is more common practice. In about 10 years of ActionScript 3 development I cannot remember once needing to use `call()` with a different `thisArgument`.

Comment: 1) I was not getting an error because my compiler is not on strict mode. 2) I had never made the difference between a class method and a function object. Thanks!